# Junit 5 en Netbeans 12

Tags: junit-5, netbeans-12

antes de formular la pregunta he buscado por internet y no he encontrado que es lo que puede ser. Lo mas probable es que sea un detalle que soy incapaz de ver.

Estoy empezando con las pruebas unitarias y estoy haciendo un test simplemente para probar la funcionalidad.

El entorno es Ubuntu 20.02 con NetBeans 12.
Como java platform tengo seleccionada java 1.8 ya que es la que necesito para otros proyectos
en soruve binary format tambien tengo seleccionada java 1.8 por el mismo motivo
Ambos los he cambiado a java 14 para probar con el mismo resultado
En Libraries -> Compile Test, existe la libreria jUnit 5, sin embargo no en libreries --> Run Test. Esto no se si es importante

no utilizo ni maven ni nada. Es un proyecto nuevo de "Java with Ant" --> Java Application. Solo con la clase principal main.
Creo una clase junit de 0 y también he pobado a crearla a partir de la clase que me crea con el main.

clase main:

```
package javaapplication2;

/**
 *
 * @author demorgar
 */
public class JavaApplication2 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
    }
    
}
```

clases junit:

```
    package javaapplication2;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

/**
 *
 * @author demorgar
 */
public class JavaApplication2Test {
    
    public JavaApplication2Test() {
    }

    /**
     * Test of main method, of class JavaApplication2.
     */
    @Test
    public void testMain() {
        System.out.println("main");
        String[] args = null;
        JavaApplication2.main(args);
        fail("The test case is a prototype.");
    }
    
}

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package main;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Disabled;

/**
 *
 * @author demorgar
 */
public class NewEmptyJUnitTest {
    
    public NewEmptyJUnitTest() {
    }
    
    @BeforeAll
    public static void setUpClass() {
    }
    
    @AfterAll
    public static void tearDownClass() {
    }
    
    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
    }
    
    @AfterEach
    public void tearDown() {
    }
    
    @Test
    public void aTest () {
        assertEquals(1,1);
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testB () {
        assertEquals(2,2);
    }
    
}
```

El resultado siempre es el mismo. El build es correcto, pero notifica no "test executed".

En la primera ejecución da muchos warnings y he tenido que añadir la biblioteca de apiguardian-api-1.0.0

Resultado en el output:

```
   ant -f /home/user/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication2 -Djavac.includes=javaapplication2/JavaApplication2Test.java -Dnb.internal.action.name=test.single -Dtest.includes=javaapplication2/JavaApplication2Test.java -Dtest.class=javaapplication2.JavaApplication2Test -Dignore.failing.tests=true test-single
init:
Deleting: /home/user/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication2/build/built-jar.properties
deps-jar:
Updating property file: /home/user/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication2/build/built-jar.properties
compile:
Created dir: /home/user/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication2/build/test/classes
Compiling 1 source file to /home/user/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication2/build/test/classes
Copied 1 empty directory to 1 empty directory under /home/user/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication2/build/test/classes
compile-test-single:
Created dir: /home/user/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication2/build/test/results
No tests executed.
test-single:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Edito: 1/10/2020
He probado de crear un test con jUnit 4. En este caso si funciona, se ejecuta como se espera respindiendo los test true o fail según sea. Si después de crear el test con jUnit 4 creo uno de jUnit 5.6, me sigue cogiendo el motor de jUnit 4, lo he comprobado intentando poner etiquetas de jUnit 5 como @Disabled, la cual no funciona, y si pongo @ignore si funciona. Así que debe ser algún problema de las librerías por defecto que tiene NetBeans 12. Poruqe no lo he conseguido de ninguna de las maneras.
Edito: 1/10/2020:  He encontrado una referencia en [stackoverflow en ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61800642/the-junit-test-fails-in-netbeans-11-3-ide-could-not-find-or-load-main-class), en la que se desprende que en netbeans 11.3 no había manera, que había que usar jUnit 4